# Magento 2 Order Email with Single Item Price

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

i was wondering how i can have in confirmation email the single item price

like in the image

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? None of the answers here work for me to get the unit price in file app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/Magento_Sales/templates/email/item/invoice/default.phtml

Comment: I added single item price using above example. Now how can I align the total section accordingly?
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP5PM.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP5PM.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the following file to your theme folder like below:

`/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items.phtml`

to

`/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items.phtml`

Now add one more th to thead with your required heading name.

Again copy the following file to your theme folder like below:

`/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml`

to

`/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml`

Here you can one td with the same position as th for heading. You will get the unit price by $_item->getPrice(). Now you need to format this value with currency symbol.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

for the email
/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

`$_order - > formatPrice($_item->getPrice());`

above working for me !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit / override following 2 files, if you want to show in sales order emails.

> 1. app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml
> 2. app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Answer (score 0):

```
<?=  $_order->formatPrice($_item->getPrice()) ?>
```

Comment: Please add some more details about it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Please check and override the files mentioned below in your custom theme, then verify the email output.**

**To customize the table header, you need to override the following file and update its content.**

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml
```

**Please add the following code to the existing file.**

```
<th class="item-price">
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>
</th>
```

**To display the product price value in the HTML of a simple product, use the code provided below.**

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

**Please add the following code to the existing file.**

```
<td class="item-price">
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $_order->formatPrice($_item->getPrice()) ?>
</td>
```

**Various types of product HTML are sourced from different files. Please ensure that you are overriding the correct file for your specific product.**

**For example, HTML for bundle products is sourced from the following path:**

```
vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/templates/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

**After that, there is a misalignment in the total section of your email due to the addition of a new column. To correct this, you need to override the following two files. Add a new  tag within the Total section and update the colspan attribute to colspan="4". If there is already colspan="3", update it to colspan="4"**

```
vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/templates/order/tax.phtml

vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml
```